# How do I change the settings in Jupyterlab so that autocomplete doesn't show me an option to choose "file" or "path?"

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm not sure how else to describe it but it's very annoying and I would like to disable to "file" option since that doesn't autocomplete the path properly.

Comment: "since that doesn't autocomplete the path properly" - please file a [bug report](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues) with more details and this will be fixed